# How to view and play video after getting from json?

Tags: android, json, android-videoview

I am getting response of json perfectly,but I want to display the video file which I am getting from json,all the data get succesfully from json,below is response of my json,can any one tell me how to do it??  I am using videoview for that

```
{    
 "user_login_id":"2650",   
"user_total_video":"1",  
"max_upload_video":"1",  
"video_id":"487",  
"video_status":"Admin Approve Remaining",  
"video":"http:\/\/mywebss.com\/uploads\/user\/2650\/small\/Denger_But_Funny_Bomb_Blas(www.FunsMaza.in).3gp"  
 }
```

[image]

```
public class VideoList extends Activity{

private String User_IDs;
private String total;
private String max;
private String vidid;
private String vidsta;
private String vd;
private VideoView vides;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private ImageAdapter adapter;
private Button btnvideoupload;
private Button btndelete;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fullvideo);



    User_IDs=this.getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
    System.out.println("photo upload view user id"+User_IDs);

    total=this.getIntent().getStringExtra("totalvideos");
    System.out.println("photo total "+total);

    max=this.getIntent().getStringExtra("maxvideos");
    System.out.println("photo maximum "+max);

    vidid=this.getIntent().getStringExtra("videoid");
    System.out.println("photo maximum "+vidid);

    vidsta=this.getIntent().getStringExtra("vidstatus");
    System.out.println("photo maximum "+vidsta);

    vd=this.getIntent().getStringExtra("vids");
    System.out.println("photo maximum "+vd);

    btnvideoupload=(Button)findViewById(R.id.goforuploadvid);

    btnvideoupload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),VideoUpload.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", User_IDs);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    btndelete=(Button)findViewById(R.id.deletevid);
    btndelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    /* viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
       adapter = new ImageAdapter(VideoList.this);
       viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);*/

    //Creating MediaController  
 MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);  
     mediaController.setAnchorView(vides);          

    vides=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoviewfull);
    vides.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(vd.toString()));
    vides.setMediaController(new MediaController(VideoList.this));
    vides.requestFocus();
    vides.start();


       }
```

Comment: where is the video stored?

Comment: i just know we can use videoview so i added in xml and find it in my java class

Comment: I see. where is the video you want to display stored?

Comment: what is the value of `vd` ?

Comment: vd is video what alredy is in database and i am fetching it from json

Comment: is it its value `abcd.3gp`?

Comment: yes and see update my question with ui desgin

Answer (score 0):

To Play Video from url you can use this code:

```
VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("abcd.mp4"));
myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
myVideoView.requestFocus();
myVideoView.start();
```

Comment: its static..and i am getting data from json..yet thanks anjali

Comment: you can replace abcd.mp4 with your url i.e. vd.toString()

Comment: can you provide me any one url which you are getting from json??

Comment: tthe response of my url is i am getting is in my question

Comment: abcd.3gp is it full file path? is this file exist in local folder?

Comment: see again i upload one video and edited in my question

Comment: Test with this url : http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.3gp. your json url is not working in browser too. there is some issue with your json url only.

Comment: there mywebss means to mywebsitename its not real name..and url working fine othervise it was not possible to get response..i am getting response perfectly..only i am not able to display video..read question again